# Why does all information disappear when i press a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im creating a website where you can change languages, in this case Polish-English. All text changes languages when it needs to. However, my website includes a menu that uses anchors right at the start, when clicked it scrolls down to the certain 'chapter', the problem is that when i have the language in polish, it makes everything disappear, but it scrolls when i have it in english

```
<div id="en" class="menu">
        <h1>kaszam.ga</h1>
        <p id="dateCountEn"></p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aboutMe">about me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pcSpecs">pc specs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#accounts">accounts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#usefulLinks">useful links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="pl" class="menu">
        <h1>kaszam.ga</h1>
        <p id="dateCountPl"></p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aboutMe">o mnie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pcSpecs">specyfikacje kompa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#accounts">konta</a></li>
            <li><a href="#usefulLinks">przydatne linki</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="spacer2" id="aboutMe"></div>

    <section>
        <div id="en">
            <h1>About me</h1>
            <p>My name is Maksym Kasza</p>
            <p>I was born on 23rd November 2001 (23/11/2001) in Poland</p>
            <p id="ageEn"></p>
            <p>I've been living in England since 2008</p>
            <p>I can speak 2 languages fluently</p>
            <p>This website was created by me</p>
        </div>
        <div id="pl">
            <h1>O mnie</h1>
            <p>Nazywam się Maksym Kasza</p>
            <p>Urodziłem się 23 listopada 2001 (23.11.2001) w Polsce</p>
            <p id="agePl"></p>
            <p>Mieszkam w Anglii od 2008 roku</p>
            <p>Potrafię płynnie mówić w 2-óch językach</p>
            <p>Ta strona została stworzona przeze mnie</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Please post an example demonstrating your problem on jsbin.com.  There is a lot of code missing here (no JavaScript for example).

Comment: Please include your full code or a live demo, as we can not reproduce on our end

Comment: One problem I see right away is that you have multiple elements using the same `id` - this is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: @jnylen http://jsbin.com/keqabicede/edit Hopefully this is what you need, wont let you to change to english, but only polish doesnt work

Comment: @jnylen While you're correct in asking for code, it's actually better to *discourage* users from using external resources like JSBin. Not only do the posting rules specify that code must be *"in the question itself"*, but external resources can go down or be removed over time, thus the question becomes useless to future readers. Inline, runnable code (similar to jsbin, plunkr, jsfiddle, etc) can be included in the question by using the [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) button.

Comment: Add your script(javascript/jquery..) here.

Comment: That's weird that you have some vanilla JS in the JS section of JSBin... **And** some jQuery equivalent in the HTML markup section. -- The reason why *«all information dissapear»* is because the `body` has the `en` class... Which is hidden on click (to change language).

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your click listener that's attached to the polish links:

```
<body class="en">

$("#pl").click(function(){
    $(".en").hide();
    $(".pl").show();
});
```

Your body has the class en, so when you click any polish link you hide the whole body.